# For loop is not unrolling in chisel

Tags: hardware, chisel

I was trying to understand how we are generating verilog code out of "for" loop in chisel.
Generally verilog code used to unroll body as many time as loop progress but here in chisel it's only unrolling it once.

```
val io = new Bundle {

    val a = UInt(INPUT, 2)

    val output = UInt(OUTPUT, 2)
  }

    io.output := UInt(0)

    for(j <- 0 to 4){

      io.output := io.a
    }
```

Corresponding verilog code for the above program is :

```
module LutSimpleALU(

    input [1:0] io_a,
    output[1:0] io_output
);

   assign io_output = io_a;

endmodule
```

it would be very helpful if someone can tell how for loop is working.

Comment: In for block, loop counter variable "j" is not used, so that for loop just executes "io.output := io_a" repeatedly. As the result, verilog extracts the first execution of for block ,i.e.,  "io.output := io_a" .

Comment: That means i have to use "j" always in order for loop to work?

Comment: You execute same code " io.output := io.a" again and again. Verilog thought that repeated execution is meaningless and execute once is enough.  I don't know the way to execute differently in each execution of for block in which the loop counter never be used.

Comment: Can you share a small example in which loop unrolling will work ?

Comment: A part of code "for(j<-0 to 4){ a[j] := b[j]*j } " will be unrolled as "assign a[0] = 0; assing a[1]=b[1]; assign a[2]=b[2]*2; assign a[3]=b[3]*3; a[4]=b[4]*4; ". These five operations are independant each other, so could be executed in parallel.

Comment: Fumu thank you for your response.. i have one more doubt. "val io = new Bundle {

    val a = UInt(INPUT, 2)
    val b = UInt(INPUT, 2)
    val opcode = UInt(INPUT, 2)
    val output = UInt(OUTPUT, 2)
  }

  for(j <- 0 to 4){

    io.opcode := io.a + io.b
  }

  io.output := io.opcode"  In this example can you tell me how loop is going to unroll. I actually writing a parser so i should know how many times a for loop is going to unroll.

Comment: Your loop may be unrolled to "assign io_output = io_a; assign io_output = io_a; assign io_output = io_a; assign io_output = io_a; assign io_output = io_a;", and then optimizer reduces overlapped operations to one operation "assign io_output = io_a;" that is what you got.

Comment: Can i generalize loop unrolling as, repeating all the statements as many times as loop unroll and if there is no dependency between successive statements i will replace one.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your for loop is doing the same thing for each iteration. You aren't using the "j" iterator variable anywhere, so this is what it expands to:

```
io.output := io.a
io.output := io.a
io.output := io.a 
io.output := io.a
```

The semantics here is that the last writer wins, so the last statement of "io.output = io.a" would be the final value. In fact, the previous three statements mean nothing, so they would be pruned from the graph.